# How to fetch the values for a column based on existing columns

Tags: sql, teradata

My requirement is to fetch the data in the below format: If i have the same value for COL1 , then the lowest value of COL2 should get populated for all the rows and corresponding value of COL3 has to be populated (This can be hardcoded as it will not change) and value of COL4 corresponding to the lowest value of COL2 should get populated for all the rows.(This cannot be hardcoded)

Existing data in the table

```
SELECT COL1 , COL2 , COL3 , COL4 FROM TABLE1 

COL1  COL2  COL3  COL4
1234  01    ABC   YYY
1234  02    DEF   ZZZ
```

My expected output is:

```
COL1  COL2  COL3  COL4
1234  01    ABC   YYY
1234  01    ABC   YYY
```

I tried the below query and I got the output for COL2 and COL3 but for COL4 I am not getting.

```
SELECT
  COL1,
  MIN(COL2) OVER (PARTITION BY COL1)     AS COL2NEW,
  CASE WHEN COL2NEW = 1 THEN 'ABC'
       WHEN COL2NEW = 2 THEN 'DEF' END   AS COL3NEW,
  COL4
FROM
  TABLE1
```

Kindly guide me to get the appropriate output for COL4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is quite ambiguous, but I think `FIRST_VALUE()` is the analytic function you're looking for...

```
SELECT
  COL1,
  MIN(COL2) OVER (PARTITION BY COL1)     AS COL2NEW,
  CASE WHEN COL2NEW = 1 THEN 'ABC'
       WHEN COL2NEW = 2 THEN 'DEF' END   AS COL3NEW,
  FIRST_VALUE(COL4) OVER (PARTITION BY COL1
                              ORDER BY COL2
                          ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
                         )
                            AS COL4NEW
FROM
  TABLE1
```

It takes the first value of `COL4` after sorting the partition by `COL2`.  This means that all rows in the partition get the same value in `COL4NEW`, and that value is from the input row with the lowest value in `COL2`.